# Performance impact in having a single import per line

Tags: python, python-import

does anybody know if there is a performance difference between having all imports from one module in a single line vs one per line.
For example, having:

```py
from a import A, B, C, D, E, F, G
```

instead of:

```py
from a import A
from a import B
from a import C
from a import D
from a import E
from a import F
from a import G
```

I'm trying to convince my team to use `reorder-python-imports` in our pre-commit hooks and this doubt is the only obstacle that prevents me from adding it.

Comment: The performance difference is negligible, if any at all. The typical convention is to have all names from the same module imported on the same line, i.e. `from a import A, B, C, D, E, F, G`.

Comment: @blhsing Thanks! Do you know where I could find information about how imports are implemented on the background?
I know that the convention is to have them in the same line (or at least in pep8 it says that it is "Correct" to do so), but having one per line as suggested by reorder-python-imports makes a lot of sense to avoid merge conflicts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Combining imports is technically faster but there should not be a noticeable performance difference in real world usage. Python modules execute only once, on their first time being imported. After being initialized, you only incur the negligible cost of the additional import statements themselves.

As long as you only do top-level imports, your imports will only ever execute during startup anyway. By combining them you might at best manage to shave off a negligible amount of milliseconds during startup. Read the [Python docs on the import mechanism](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html).

Here is my machine's performance after a million repetitions each:

**test1.py**

```
from timeit import timeit

print(timeit("""
from socket import socket
from socket import create_connection
from socket import has_dualstack_ipv6
from socket import getaddrinfo
from socket import gethostbyaddr
"""))
# Prints 2.8450163
```

**test2.py**

```
from timeit import timeit

print(timeit("""
from socket import socket, create_connection, has_dualstack_ipv6, getaddrinfo, gethostbyaddr
"""))
# Prints 0.6992155
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer @Dennis, the timeit that you used in your example helped me to use it on my own project and compare what the real results would be.